# OpenLayer3 projection EPSG parameters

Tags: openlayers-3

I doing some simple OpenLayer3 maps, but I do transform map to coordinates 
[0, 0] with command

```
  view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(
        [0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 1
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
      layers: layers,
      //renderer: exampleNS.getRendererFromQueryString(),
      target: 'map',
      view: view
    });
```

But I dont know what for are responsible 2nd and 3rd EPSG parameters?

ol.proj.transform(
            [0, 0], **'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'**),

ADDED: more about projection is here: 
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html
but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All EPSG numbers are just names on different types of projections used when dealing with maps. This can be quite confusing. One of the ways to look at it is just different coordinate systems placed on the earth.

EPSG:4324, also called WGS84 is a coordinate system that we normally would think of when dealing with map coordinates. This is where we use longitude and latitute. This coordinate system is a spherical coordinate system with degrees as units.

EPSG:3857 - also galled EPSG:900913. This is just a different coordinate system, but it is often used by map components such as Google, Bing etc. If the map provider you use only understand this coordinate system, you will need to convert your coordinates to this before using them in that component.

When coding your map application and you do a lot of handling and calculation on coordinates, I would recommend using EPSG:3857 internally in the app (as long as the map provider use that) and only do transformations when getting data from user or when you need to display coordinates in another projection.